# Why does running the query through JDBC take longer than the time reported by EXPLAIN

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a SQL query, first I analyzed the query by executing and it is taking less than 1 ms.

So I used the query in my spring boot app, and tried to execute it using

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, params, new validationMapper());
```

but when I see the time, it is 19212ms.

Why this much time difference?

Comment: With "first I analyzed" do you mean you ran `explain (analyze)` for it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , yes i ran query on some PgAdmin , and then i used explain (analyze)

Comment: `explain (analyze)` does not include the time it takes to send the data from the server to the client. So the runtime in your application will include that overhead  (which could be substantial depending on the network between server and client) and most probably the overhead of processing the data in your Java code as well (it's unclear what exactly that runtime that is logged by Spring includes)

Comment: If 20 second is the time it takes on your Java app (as a_horse_with_no_name said),  you should check how much it takes on the pgsql server alone (I think you can see this in pg logs or something). But 20 second vs 1ms seems a lot to me. You don't use any ORM framework (like hibernate) ?

Comment: @Asoub , does add another overhead here , because we are just using simple jdbctemplate .  yes it seems as mentioned above , it involve the data transmission over head to the spring application (java code) from the db server . Because i just take another input to sql query  where the result have data with small size , then i saw it is 400 ms only ,